# Could this be more efficient in Go?

Tags: go, grep

I wrote a piece of code to illustrate the standard command `grep` in Go, but the speed is
far behind it, could someone give me any advances? here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func parse_args() (file, pat string) {
    if len(os.Args) < 3 {
        log.Fatal("usage: gorep2 <file_name> <pattern>")
    }

    file = os.Args[1]
    pat = os.Args[2]
    return
}

func readFile(file string, to chan<- string) {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    freader := bufio.NewReader(f)
    for {
        line, er := freader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if er == nil {
            to <- string(line)
        } else {
            break
        }

    }
    close(to)
}

func grepLine(pat string, from <-chan string, result chan<- bool) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for line := range from {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(l string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            if strings.Contains(l, pat) {
                result <- true
            }
        }(string(line))
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(result)
}

func main() {
    file, pat := parse_args()
    text_chan := make(chan string, 10)
    result_chan := make(chan bool, 10)

    go readFile(file, text_chan)
    go grepLine(pat, text_chan, result_chan)

    var total uint = 0
    for r := range result_chan {
        if r == true {
            total += 1
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Total %d\n", total)
}
```

The `time` in Go:

```
>>> time gogrep /var/log/task.log DEBUG 

Total 21089

real    0m0.156s
user    0m0.156s
sys 0m0.015s
```

The `time` in `grep`:

```
>>> time grep DEBUG /var/log/task.log | wc -l

21089

real    0m0.069s
user    0m0.046s
sys 0m0.064s
```

Comment: refer to the `time` above, Go wins in `sys`, but lose in the `user` part, dose that mean my code eat the the time?

Comment: It seems that a go routine per line (refer `grepLine`) might be an overhead you can remove.  Throwing multiple lines at each go routine would mean less time creating go routines and more time doing text searches. If you have not already I recomend Rob Pikes http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1

Comment: You're reading each line multiple times: scanning for \n in bufio, then copying the bytes to a string, then scanning for DEBUG. Only the latter is being done in parallel in your code. I'd expect grep does everything in a single pass.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For an easily reproducible benchmark, I counted the number of occurences of the text "and" in Shakespeare.

```
gogrep:

$ go build gogrep.go && time ./gogrep /home/peter/shakespeare.txt and 
Total 21851
real    0m0.613s
user    0m0.651s
sys 0m0.068s

grep:

$ time grep and /home/peter/shakespeare.txt | wc -l
21851
real    0m0.108s
user    0m0.107s
sys 0m0.014s

petergrep:

$ go build petergrep.go && time ./petergrep /home/peter/shakespeare.txt and 
Total 21851
real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.092s
sys 0m0.008s
```

petergrep is written in Go. It's fast.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func parse_args() (file, pat string) {
    if len(os.Args) < 3 {
        log.Fatal("usage: petergrep <file_name> <pattern>")
    }
    file = os.Args[1]
    pat = os.Args[2]
    return
}

func grepFile(file string, pat []byte) int64 {
    patCount := int64(0)
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if bytes.Contains(scanner.Bytes(), pat) {
            patCount++
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    return patCount
}

func main() {
    file, pat := parse_args()
    total := grepFile(file, []byte(pat))
    fmt.Printf("Total %d\n", total)
}
```

Data: [Shakespeare: pg100.txt](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt)

Comment: This is an interesting benchmark but not strictly valid - you've implemented `fgrep`, without regular expressions. It isn't fair to compare `petergrep` against `grep`.

Comment: ...but you *have* answered the question nicely.

Comment: Also, take into account that grep is returning all lines matching the expression and passing it to wc command. A better benchmark would be running "grep -Fc". I did it in my computer with both "grep -c" and "grep -Fc" and found out that both achieve a slight improvement over your implementation: 2 +/- 2 milliseconds better than your solution. Which says that it's still a pretty good implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Go regular expressions are fully utf-8 and I think that has some overhead. They also have [a different theoretical basis](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) meaning they will always run in a time proportional to the length of the input.  It is noticeable that Go regexps just aren't as fast as the pcre regexp in use by other languages.  If you look at the [benchmarks game shootouts for the regexp test](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=regexdna) you'll see what I mean.

You can always use the [pcre library directly](https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre) if you want a bit more speed though.

Comment: The question does not use Go regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

A datapoint on the relevance of UTF-8 in regexp parsing: I've a long-used custom perl5 script for source grepping.  I recently modified it to support UTF-8 so it could match fancy golang symbol names.  It ran a FULL ORDER OF MAGNITUDE slower in repeated tests.  So while golang regexp's do pay a price for the predictability of it's runtime, we also have to factor UTF-8 handling into the equation.

Comment: It appears that this answer could be more appropriately posted as a comment.